# Do OctoPrint or Marlin support "ironing" and additional printing states?

Tags: marlin, ultimaker-cura, g-code, octoprint, scripts

Currently, OctoPrint shows a printer state such as "Printing" as shown below:

[image: OctoPrint State]

But is there is a way such as via a Cura script or OctoPrint Plugin to insert a special g-code and let OctoPrint show "State: Ironing" instead? This is especially helpful since I usually only iron my top layer, so it's only busy ironing from a specific layer.

Or does Marlin firmware already know and support states other than "stopped, paused, printing" such as ironing, tramming, leveling, heating?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask this at the OctoPrint github as a feature request?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will post it there too.

Comment: Looking at the API specification, https://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/printer.html#retrieve-the-current-printer-state, the states are predefined. It would require rewriting the OctoPrint software to add more states, more specifically, how to detect them. Is this something you aim to answer the question?

Comment: I see. I guess I'm looking ultimately for something that is not available in OctoPrint currently. Alternatively I'm thinking to simply use M118 before and after things like leveling, heating, cooling etc. Seems status is not possible for now.